# Error 500: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, sessionfactory

I'm getting this error when I try to upload a picture in my project. The project executes fine until it has to effectively upload the picture to the database (I'm using postgresql), but this last step never works.

The following code was updated having considered the answers below.

Here's my controller (a part of it):

```
@Autowired
private FileUploadImpl fileUploadImpl;

...

@RequestMapping(value = "publish4" ,method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView publish4(@Valid @ModelAttribute("fourthPublicationForm") final FourthPublicationForm form, final BindingResult errors,
                             @RequestParam("type") String type, @RequestParam("operation") String operation , @RequestParam CommonsMultipartFile[] fileUpload) {
    if (errors.hasErrors()) {
        //return helloPublish3(form,operation,type);
    }
    System.out.println("operation: "+ operation);
    System.out.println("type: "+ type);
    ps.create(form.getTitle(), form.getAddress(), operation, form.getPrice(), form.getDescription(), 
            type, form.getBedrooms(), form.getBathrooms(), form.getFloorSize(), form.getParking());

    if (fileUpload != null && fileUpload.length > 0) {
        for (CommonsMultipartFile aFile : fileUpload){

            System.out.println("Saving file: " + aFile.getOriginalFilename());

            UploadFile uploadFile = new UploadFile();
            uploadFile.setAddress(form.getAddress());
            uploadFile.setData(aFile.getBytes());
            fileUploadImpl.save(uploadFile);               
        }
    }
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/hello/home");
}
```

This is fileUploadDao in interface:

```
public interface FileUploadDao {
   void save(UploadFile uploadFile);
}
```

This is in services:

```
@Service
public class FileUploadImpl {

    @Autowired
    private FileUploadDao fileUploadDao;

    public FileUploadImpl() {
    }

    @Transactional
    public void save(UploadFile uploadFile) {
        fileUploadDao.save(uploadFile);
    }

}
```

THe following in persistence:

```
@Repository
public class FileUploadDAOImpl implements FileUploadDao {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public FileUploadDAOImpl() {
    }

    public FileUploadDAOImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }


    public void save(UploadFile uploadFile) {
       sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(uploadFile);
    }
}
```

I got this in WebConfig.java (among other stuff)

```
@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
   LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
   sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
   sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(
       new String[] { "ar.edu.itba.paw" }
   );
   //sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

   return sessionFactory;
}

@Autowired
@Bean(name = "fileUploadDao")
public FileUploadDao getUserDao(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    return new FileUploadDAOImpl(sessionFactory);
}

@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver getCommonsMultipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(20971520);   // 20MB
    multipartResolver.setMaxInMemorySize(1048576);  // 1MB
    return multipartResolver;
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(
    SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
    return txManager;
}
```

A little bit more of the error:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:106)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1014)
at ar.edu.itba.paw.persistence.FileUploadDAOImpl.save(FileUploadDAOImpl.java:25)
at ar.edu.itba.paw.webapp.controller.HelloWorldController.publish4(HelloWorldController.java:260)
```

I've seen other questions where the answer was the lack of use of "transactional". I'm using that annotation here, but I'm not sure if the way it's 100% correct.

Comment: @OldPro I've tried the solutions over there but they don't seem to work or maybe I'm not understanding them well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First remove `@Transactional` from `FileUploadDAOImpl`.

Change base package accordingly,

```
sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(
   new String[] { "base.package.to.scan" } 
);
```

`base.package.to.scan` seems like invalid base package naming, change it to `ar.edu.itba.paw`.

You need a transaction manager to get use of `@Transactional`. Add it to `WebConfig`

```
@Bean
@Autowired
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(
    SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory());
    return txManager;
}
```

This might get this code work, give it a try.

UPDATE: Also make sure following annotations present on `WebConfig` class,

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"ar.edu.itba.paw"})
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.PROXY)
public class WebConfig {
    // code
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the base package was for sure wrong. I've updated my code above using your answer. I still get the exact same exception.

Comment: @Stackoverflowed side note: since you're using field autowired dependency for `sessionFactory` no need of `getUserDao` method in `WebConfig.java`

Comment: @Stackoverflowed did you add required annotations on `WebConfig.java` class ? Please see the update.

Comment: I added @EnableTransactionManagement without the mode because I could get AdviceMode resolved (maybe I need a depedency or something?). Anyways that fixed the exception, I'm getting a new one "org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet" but that's probably for another question. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

As you said from the first place, you have confused the actual layers. Still you could make it work properly in your situation but lets discuss a bit your implementation.

- `FileUploadDao` is it a DAO or is it a Service ?
- `FileUploadImpl` seems that you're confusing `@Service` with `@Repository` , 
  maybe reading this out might help you. [Spring Data Repositories](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html) , [Spring Service Annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Service.html)
- You ve made a transactional method , `save` in which i cannot say what you want to achieve exactly. You are also autowiring both `FileUploadDao` and `SessionFactory`, although you want to implement the first and inside the method you are trying to persist the object twice by first calling `save` upon the repository (thats a `StackOverflowError` from the first place, but you are lucky because Spring knows what to autowire) and then you are trying to call save a second time upon the Hibernate's SessionFactory , which breaks the abstract JPA contract. Also if you noticed , the error at the logs you posted , comes from the second save.
- `@Transactional` not going to discuss how is this working , as you haven't posted your whole app-config. But again , you could read [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html) for more info.

So based on the examples you shared , i am going to prepare 2 cases which might help you understand whats going on underneath.

1. **First Case** , Spring DATA , not really care if its Hibernate or another JPA provider underneath.

Your `FileUploadImpl` Becomes : `FileUploadService`

```
@Service
public class FileUploadService {

    @Autowired
    private FileUploadDao fileUploadDao;

    public FileUploadService() {
    }

    @Transactional
    public void save(UploadFile uploadFile) {
        fileUploadDao.save(uploadFile);
    }

}
```

Inside your controller , you are Autowiring the Service (layer) not directly the Repository/DAO(layer). There is not anything that stops you tho , its just a matter of design(if you still not get that point, raise another question).

A part of your part's Controller

```
    @Autowired
    private FileUploadService fileUploadService;


    @RequestMapping(value = "publish4" ,method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView publish4(@Valid @ModelAttribute("fourthPublicationForm") final FourthPublicationForm form, final BindingResult errors,
                             @RequestParam("type") String type, @RequestParam("operation") String operation , @RequestParam CommonsMultipartFile[] fileUpload) {
       .........
       fileUploadService.save(uploadFile);   
}
```

2. **Second Case** , if you really want to use hibernate goodies , then there is not any reason autowiring the Repository , but simply implement those calls by yourself.

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Component
public class FileUploadDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public FileUpload save(FileUpload obj) {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(obj);
    }

    public FileUpload merge(FileUpload obj) {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge(obj);
    }

    ..... delete / update / or custom queries(SQL/JPQL/HQL) can be placed here

}
```

Your service simply exposes those methods , check the difference , i am applying the `@Transactional` annotation on this layer(ofc again you can put it in the DAO layer, but as i said its a matter of design).

```
@Service
public class FileUploadService {

    @Autowired
    private FileUploadDao fileUploadDao;

    public FileUploadService() {
    }

    @Transactional
    public UploadFile save(UploadFile uploadFile) {
        fileUploadDao.save(uploadFile);
    }

    @Transactional
    public UploadFile merge(UploadFile uploadFile) {
        fileUploadDao.merge(uploadFile);
    }

    ....rest of the methods you want to expose , or combinations of mulitple DAOs

}
```

Your controller remains the same , and thats the actual reason you need to have layers.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Unfortunately I can't get this to work. The first alternative throws the same exception and the second one throws me an exception right when I run the project (Injection of autowired dependencies failed...). I've updated my code providing more details, maybe there's something else I'm missing.

Comment: I've just updated my question with the help you provided (first alternative) and with the code of the persistence layer I forgot before. I also added webconfig.

Comment: I left FileUploadImpl with that name but I changed everything else you said.

Comment: @Stackoverflowed in your controller which dao are you autowiring ? Cause from the one posted i can see you are explicitly injecting FileUploadImpl.